# looking for light weight Linux for a old 104 pc

Tags: distribution-choice, small-distribution, lightweight

I am looking for a light weight Linux for a PC that runs at 200 Mhz with 256 Megs of RAM. I was thinking maybe Lubuntu, as the system requirements state it needs at least a Pentium 2 generation with 128 Megs of RAM. The GUI is not all that important to have, so would I be better off going with something like Ubuntu server? I was kinda hoping to go with a Ubuntu flavor due to their great support base, but I am willing to try other flavors.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll do fine with just about any distribution (save for Gentoo or LFS maybe) if you install a light desktop environment such as FVWM, fluxbox, openbox and so on. If you care for Ubuntu you can always select a server installation and install a desktop environment from the command line afterwards, there's no need to have a specific Ubuntu deviant for it.

Comment: Or you could use the [mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (~20 MB) and install what you want from there.

Answer (score 2):

There are some small variants, e.g. take a look at [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Small_Linux), [Puppy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppy_Linux) or [U-lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-lite). U-lite might meet your criteria, it's based on Ubuntu...

Comment: +1 for Puppy. Amazing distro and definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Tinycore](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/intro.html). It just needs 10MB with GUI. But if GUI is not a requirement, then you can pick any distro and not install the desktop environment. That should save you boat loads of memory space. I did the same thing with one of my old laptops. After few days, I installed X to use firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Slitaz](http://slitaz.org). It's small and good looking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good overview of Linux distributions that will run on older or lower spec hardware, it would be worth your time browsing through the posts on [KMandla's blog](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/).

He has documented the performance of a large range of distros on these sorts of machines, with insights about the strengths and weaknesses of each. He also has [a wiki](http://kmandla.wikispaces.com/) which features lighter weight CLI applications that run well in these environments.